# Error with initial_split() No common size

Tags: r

I have the following error when trying to run `initial_split()`:

> Error: No common size for `mpg`, size 32, and `in_id`, size 26.

This chunk of code has always worked for me. I assume that I must have changed some settings?

Can anyone help?

```
library(rsample)
train_test_split <- initial_split(mtcars, prop = 0.8)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Here is my output: `train_test_split
<26/6/32>`

Comment: start a new session and run again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by deleting all packages and running again.